# How to make multiple smoothing lines in ggvis?

Tags: r, ggvis

This is the code to produce a line chart with a smoother

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg) %>%
    layer_lines() %>%
    layer_smooths()
```

And this factorizes by `vs` and plot two lines of to different colors:

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke= ~ as.factor(vs)) %>%
    layer_lines()
```

But how I can add two different smoothers as well? I am trying this but don't understand why it won't work

```
mtcars %>% 
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke= ~ as.factor(vs)) %>%
    layer_lines() %>%
    layer_smooths()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can set grouping with `dplyr::group_by`:

```
library(dplyr)
library(ggvis)

mtcars %>% 
    mutate(vs = factor(vs)) %>%
    ggvis(~wt, ~mpg, stroke = ~vs) %>%
    group_by(vs) %>% 
    layer_lines() %>%
    layer_smooths()
```

[image: plot with two smooths]

Comment: Thanks, could you explain why I need that `group_by` and the grouping is not simply passed in the attribute `stroke`?

Comment: There's an example [here](http://ggvis.rstudio.com/cookbook.html) and documentation at `?layer_smooths` and `?ggvis::group_by`, but I think when it's computing a transformation of the data, you have to explicitly set grouping. Honestly, ggvis is still prettly alpha, so the behavior may yet change.

Comment: Thanks. And by the way I could not get to work my original example 'cause I have to few df for computing the smoother I guess...it would be cool to have a sort of "smoother" that would just make chart look nicer by removing sharp angles in linechart

Comment: You can adjust it to use any number of smoothers; see `?layer_model_predictions` (which is the more general form of `layer_smooths`) and `?compute_model_predictions`, which has more details about adapting it from `loess`/`gam` (defaults depending on how many points you have) to `lm`, `glm`, or whatnot.

Comment: You can also use `auto_group` instead, if you like.